# Is there a Galois theory for deformations of curves?

Tags: galois-theory, deformation-theory, ramification, branched-covers

I have some general questions about the deformations of Galois covers of curves. Suppose we are given a $G$-Galois cover $k[[z]]/k[[x]]$, where $k$ is algebraically closed of characteristic $p>0$.  Bertin and Mézard show that the deformation functor $\text{Def}_{G}$ is represented by a *versal deformation ring* $R_G$ in this [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002220000071). In addition, they give some descriptions for this ring when $G=\mathbb{Z}/p$.

I want to explore these versal deformation rings further. Therefore, I would like to know if there are other papers that also investigate these objects? Besides, I would want some suggestions about what aspects of these rings that one should learn first?

Currently, I am interested in Galois-theory-type questions about deformations like the one below.

Suppose we are given a tower of Galois extensions $$k[[x]] \xrightarrow{\phi_m} k[[y_m]] \xrightarrow{\phi_{n/m}} k[[y_n]].$$
Set $G:=\text{Gal} (k[[y_n]]/k[[x]])$, and $H:=\text{Gal} (k[[y_n]]/k[[y_m]])$. How do the versal deformation rings $R_{G}$, $R_{H}$, and $R_{G/H}$ relate?

For instance, there are canonical maps $\text{Def}_{G} \xrightarrow{\text{ind}} \text{Def}_{G/H}$ and $\text{Def}_{G} \xrightarrow{\text{res}} \text{Def}^{G/H}_{H}$ (which, on the tangent level, coincides with the familiar restriction map in group cohomology $H^1(G, \text{Der}_k k[[z]]) \xrightarrow{\text{res}} H^1(H, \text{Der}_k k[[z]])^{G/H}$). See this [manuscript](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0352) for more details. One of my ongoing projects is to show that the map $\text{ind}$ is surjective when $G$ is cyclic.

Note that understanding these deformations also equates to understanding the geometry of the moduli space of $G$-Galois covers. Furthermore, knowing the geometry of a moduli space, in turn, supports the study of invariants over flat families of objects parameterized by the space. The most well-known among them are $p$-rank, $a$-number, and Newton polygons. I would also like to hear about other research that may benefit from this study?